# Edit item in BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, bindinglist

it is code edit item in list

```
List<class1> lst = new List<class1>();

int index = lst.FindLastIndex(s => s.Number == textBox6.Text);
if(index != -1) { lst[index] = new Class1() { ... }; }
```

please convert in code for BindingList

```
BindingList<class1> lst = new BindingList<class1>();
```

thanx

Comment: "it is code edit item in list" -- @mah, is there any chance you could use google to translate your words into english?

Comment: All your base are belong to us

Comment: BTW, `s => c.Number` is wrong, should be `s => s.Number` or `c => c.Number`. Also, "B" and "L" in `BindingList` are uppercase.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ?

```
var item = bindingList.Select((Item,Index) => new { Item, Index })
                      .LastOrDefault(x => x.Item.Number == textBox6.Text);
if (item != null)
{
    bindingList[item.Index] = new Class1() { ... };
}
```

Comment: Error: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Number' and no extension method 'Number' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you mean is x.Index.Number

Comment: @mah_85: No, copy my code again. Probably you've copied my first version containing a typo (i.e. `Item` and `Index` in the wrong order)